# Problem with using a taxonomy and taxonomy term referece field to organize my site content

Tags: taxonomy-terms

I have created a taxonomy called category in order to organize my website with Drupal 7.

I have tier 2s like cómo-aprender-inglés (how to learn English). If I create a basic page and select cómo aprender inglés as the term reference I create the following node `http://www.brays.es/es/cómo-aprender-inglés/cómo-aprender-inglés`. However, I would like the node to appear as `http://www.brays.es/es/cómo-aprender-inglés`. Is this possible?

At the moment:

1. I am hiding the node title so that a user navigating the site cannot access the full node view (cómo-aprender-inglés/cómo-aprender-inglés).
2. I have prevented that URL from being picked up by search engines by selecting this option in the Metatag module.
   I think my solution is a bit messy and I don't think it is the best option. What can I do?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The two points made 'at the moment' are a bit unclear to me. Could you clarify why they are important for your main question?

Answer (score 0):

When you want to automatically generate paths for nodes/taxonomies, using a specific 'pattern', the module [Pathauto](https://www.drupal.org/project/pathauto) is the way to go.

By using the token of the selected/entered taxonomy term on the node, you can create the requested URL.